# strapi admin panel users permissions init 404

Tags: node.js, strapi, mongodb-atlas

I have been recently testing out strapi. However i ran into some issues yesterday and cant seem to understand what really going on. I am asking this question here since most users ran into a statusCode 403 unlike mine which returned 404 (not found). Everything was working fine until i recently installed stripe 8.81.0.
At the moment when i do strapi develop/start , the admin on the console returns 200 but however when i try to go there through the browser i get a user-permissions/init 404. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the strapi-plugin-users-permissions but no changes.
I am on:

```
strapi 3.1.3 node 12.18.0 npm 6.14.4 mongodb cloud atlas
```

console out if it helps:

```
Welcome back!
To manage your project �, go to the administration panel at:
http://localhost:1337/admin

To access the server ⚡️, go to:
http://localhost:1337

[2020-08-03T17:36:41.084Z] debug GET /admin (47 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:41.908Z] debug GET /admin/runtimemain.07da870a.js (30 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:41.908Z] debug GET /admin/main.b045701d.chunk.js (2 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:41.084Z] debug GET /admin (47 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:41.908Z] debug GET /admin/runtimemain.07da870a.js (30 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:41.908Z] debug GET /admin/main.b045701d.chunk.js (2 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:42.986Z] debug GET /users-permissions/init (4 ms) 404
[2020-08-03T17:36:52.245Z] debug GET index.html (115 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:52.822Z] debug GET /assets/images/logo_login.png (326 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:56.190Z] debug GET index.html (87 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:36:56.407Z] debug GET /favicon.ico (20 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:37:00.069Z] debug GET /admin (3 ms) 200
[2020-08-03T17:37:01.121Z] debug GET /users-permissions/init (8 ms) 404
```

[image: console output from strapi develop script]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into this same issue. In my case, I ran `npm audit fix` to get rid of some security warnings without giving it adequate thought. Is it possible that you did something similar?

Looking at the [strapi migration guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/migration-guide-3.0.x-to-3.1.x.html) in their docs, it appears that this is a result of upgrading from 3.0.x to 3.1.x.

The [migration guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/migration-guide-3.0.x-to-3.1.x.html) gives 4 steps to fix the issue. It has something to do with the way admin roles and JWT secrets work. At first glance, it appears the JWT secret has to be defined in `server.js` now and will not be auto generated as in the past.

I'm going to give it a whirl and I will report back with my results.

**EDIT**: I can confirm that [these migration instructions](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/migration-guide-3.0.x-to-3.1.x.html) resolved the issue for me. Specifically, I only had to do steps 2 & 4 because I had already installed the latest version of strapi and I don't have any custom admin panel plugins

Comment: The question was answered here: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/discussions/7305 in github. The solutions are the same. I have it already up and running. However, i did have the issue of the login page enforcing email instead of username which in my case was inconvenient since it is refusing to accept the email in the schema as i was signing in with username  before. I will gave to dig this further perhaps when am free. Thanks for the timely response however.

Comment: I already did these steps and in local it was working fine. After deploying to prod it's failing now, even thos env vars are there for the token.

Comment: @jeremy All the links you have shared here end up to 404.

Comment: Here is the correct link [Migration guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/migration-guide-3.0.x-to-3.1.x.html)

Comment: the only thing I had missed from that migration guide was:
`yarn build --clean`